# how to apply leap year check logic in cobol

Tags: cobol

I am new to COBOL and hence not familiar to all the control logic as it is quite different from other high level languages. I am having trouble in checking the date parameter while reading it from an given input file for a leap year condition. Can anyone please give the code for this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method  WS-YYYY can be defined as 9(4) DISPLAY, S9(4) DISPLAY, or S9(4) COMP.  The other variables are all defined in WORKING-STORAGE as S9(4) COMP.

```
DIVIDE WS-YYYY BY 4 GIVING YEAR-BY-4 REMAINDER YEAR-BY-4-REMAINDER. 
DIVIDE WS-YYYY BY 100 GIVING YEAR-BY-100 REMAINDER YEAR-BY-100-REMAINDER.
DIVIDE WS-YYYY BY 400 GIVING YEAR-BY-400 REMAINDER YEAR-BY-400-REMAINDER.

IF YEAR-BY-400-REMAINDER = 0
    // LEAP YEAR CODE
ELSE IF YEAR-BY-100-REMAINDER = 0 
    //  NON-LEAP YEAR CODE
ELSE IF YEAR-BY-4-REMAINDER = 0
    //  LEAP YEAR CODE
ELSE
    // NON-LEAP YEAR CODE
. (period)
```

Comment: I find EVALUATE significantly easier to read and maintain.  That may just be a style preference on my part.

Answer (score 1):

A test for leap year may be done by testing for February 29th of a given year.

Using intrinsic functions:

For standards beginning with COBOL 2000, and preferred:

```
01 WS-YYYY PIC 9(4). *> Year to test.

    IF FUNCTION TEST-DATE-YYYYMMDD (WS-YYYY * 10000 + 229) = 3
        *> The test year is not a leap year
```

Return code `3` means, "The day is not valid for the given year and month."

---

For COBOL 85 with the intrinsic functions amendment (1989):

```
01 WS-YYYY PIC 9(4). *> Year to test.
01 WS-INTEGER-DATE PIC 9(8). *> Days since Dec 31, 1600.
01 WS-DATE-INTEGER PIC 9(8). *> Format is YYYYMMDD.

    COMPUTE INTEGER-DATE = FUNCTION INTEGER-OF-DATE
        (WS-YYYY * 10000 + 228) + 1 
        *> The value will convert to either
        *> February 29th or March 1st of the test year.
    COMPUTE WS-DATE-INTEGER =
        FUNCTION DATE-OF-INTEGER (WS-INTEGER-DATE)
    IF FUNCTION MOD (WS-DATE-INTEGER 100) = 29
        *> The test year is a leap year
```

Answer (score 0):

When you look in Wikis etc, they will give you the rule divisible by 4 unless divisibile by 100 then must be divisible by 400.  That is OK but what you have to ask is

*Will my application be processing dates like 1700, 1800, 1900, 2000 or 2100?*

If then answer is yes, then proceed with @gilbertleblanc's solution.  If the answer is no, then divisible by 4 would suffice.

```
DIVIDE WS-YYYY BY 4 GIVING IGNORE REMAINDER REM. 

IF REM = 0
    *  LEAP YEAR CODE
ELSE
    * NON-LEAP YEAR CODE
.
```